Trying to use my Thinkpad dock to connect my Dell Chromebook 3110 to my Acer monitor, but the monitor isn't getting registered
I have a school issued Chromebook (model 3110, no HDMI port), and am trying to connect it to my ACER monitor (model S231HL) throught my Lenovo Thinkpad USB-C dock (model 40AY). I've connected my computer to the dock with a 10GPS usb-c cable, connected my monitor and the dock to their respective power blocks, but my Chromebook is not showing the "Displays" section in its settings, and the monitor goes into power saving mode after flashing "no signal".
My Chromebook connects to the dock fine and I can successfully use all the ports for devices (except for the display port and hdmi ports). My chromebook is supposedly able to fully support DisplayPort ALT mode through the USB-C port, but again does not have an HDMI port.
I've been able to connect the monitor to my Nintendo switch using the HDMI ports on both devices, and can confirm that that works perfectly fine as well.
I've tried different HDMI cables, tried adapting the DisplayPorts on the dock to HDMI for the monitor, but nothing will work, it all gives the same result of flashing "No signal" and going into power-saving mode.
